# Does the number of writes count when Firebase Functions writes to a Cloud Firestore database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a function in `Cloud Function` which counts the number of documents within a Collection. Every time a new document is added, the counter is increased by one. I know that we are charged for each document read, write or delete but when Firebase Functions increases the counter, does this write operation also count? Or is an internal operation and it doesn't matter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on where the Cloud Function stores the counter. If the counter is stored in a document, then each time you update the counter you are writing a document. So in that case it will indeed count as a document write.

Comment: Now it is stored in a document but where should I store the counter so the write operation does not count?

Comment: Every time you write to a document, it counts as a "document write" operation. If you don't want to incur the cost of a "document write" operation, you should keep the counter in a storage layer that doesn't change for document writes. One example of that could be the Firebase Realtime Database, but there are probably many others.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that we can use both databases in the same time. Firebase Realtime Database + Cloud Firestore are the winners. Thank you so much Frank!